# Calculating a line integral in $2$ ways

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I want to evaluate the line integral  $$\oint_{C} (3y)dx+(2x)dy$$ where $C$ is the boundary of $ 0 \le x \le \pi, \enspace 0 \le y \le \sin{x} $. I found with Green's theorem that the result is $-2:$ $$\oint_{C} (3y)dx+(2x)dy = \int\int_{R} (N_x - M_y) dA = \int\int_{R} (-1) dA = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sin{x}} (-1)  dA = -2.$$ Then, I tried to parametrize the curve and took the integral as follows, but found $2$:$$x=t, y=\sin{t}, \enspace 0\le t \le \pi \implies r(t)=<t,\sin{t}> \text{ and } F=<3y,2x>=<3\sin{t},2t>$$ and $dr/dt = <1,\cos{t}>$ so that $$F \cdot dr/dt = 3\sin{t} + 2t \cos{t}.$$ Thus, $$\oint_{C} (3y)dx+(2x)dy= \oint_{C} F \cdot dr/dt = \int_{t=0}^{t=\pi} (3\sin{t} + 2t \cos{t}) dt = \int_{t=0}^{t=\pi} 3\sin{t} dt + \int_{t=0}^{t=\pi} 2t \cos{t} dt = 6 -4 = 2.$$

I think the problem is with the orientation of $C$ because in the second case, the orientation is clockwise. Do we always take line integrals with the counter-clockwise direction? Is writing $$\oint_{C} (3y)dx+(2x)dy= \oint_{C} F \cdot dr/dt = - \int_{t=0}^{t=\pi} (3\sin{t} + 2t \cos{t}) dt$$ fix all the problems?

Comment: I see the parametrization of the upper half of the boundary: $(x,y) = (t, \sin t)$ (going around the enclosed region in the negative direction).  Where's the parametrization of the other half of the boundary $(x,y) = (t,0)$ (going around the enclosed region in the positive direction)?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#/media/File:Right-hand_grip_rule.svg) might help you decide when arcs are positively oriented or negatively oriented.

Comment: @EricTowers The parametrization $r(t) = (t,0)$ gives $F \cdot dr/dt = (0,2t) \cdot (t, 0) = 0$ so the integral over the axis is $0$ ?

Comment: For less than or greater than or equal to use "\leq" or "\geq"

Comment: You might consider `\langle`, "$\langle$", and `\rangle`, "$\rangle$" for these vector brackets.

Comment: @Ninja : Agreed.  But if you don't write something down about that, you only have half a computation.